# Point-in-time reporting in a DAX model

Tags: sql-server, ssas, dax

My current organisation has the nasty habit of reusing product codes.  This means what was say, a jumper, two years ago is now a pair of shoes.

The table these are held in is a type 2 SCD, let's call this table '`Items`' in my DAX model (I'm fairly new to DAX), e.g.

```
Item code | Description      | Valid From    |  Valid To
1000      | Jumper           | 2016-01-01    |  2016-06-01
1000      | Shoes            | 2016-06-02    |  2016-12-31
```

There is a sale table, which only has the item code in it, a quantity, value of the sale and a date, called '`Sales`' in the DAX model:

```
Item Code | SaleDate         |  Quantity     | Value
1000      | 2016-01-31       |  1            | 25.00
1000      | 2016-02-29       |  2            | 50.00
1000      | 2016-06-30       |  1            | 30.00
1000      | 2016-10-31       |  1            | 30.00
```

The desired out put therefore when querying the DAX model is as follows:

```
Item Code | Description |  Quantity (sum)  | Value (sum)
1000      | Jumper      |  3               | 75.00
1000      | Shoes       |  2               | 60.00
```

I believe this needs a calculation in the `Sales` table of my DAX model to link to the `Items` table, but struggling to come up with what I need.  I've tried doing some reading around the subject (e.g. Alberto Ferrari) but clear explanations are not really there.

Structure-wise, the sale table has a lookup reference to a calendar table but the Items table currently has no reference to any tables (it does not have unique enough entries to be linked to the `Sales` table).

Would be grateful for any pointers/ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two measures:

```
Quantity Sum =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Sales[Quantity] ),
    FILTER (
        Sales,
        [SalesDate] >= MAX ( Items[Valid From] )
            && [SalesDate] <= MAX ( Items[Valid To] )
    )
)
```

```
Sales Sum =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Sales[Value] ),
    FILTER (
        Sales,
        [SalesDate] >= MAX ( Items[Valid From] )
            && [SalesDate] <= MAX ( Items[Valid To] )
    )
)
```

Then in your client you can use a table or any visualization to show the desired output by adding `Item Code` and `Description` from `Items` table and the measures created previously.

This is the result in a Power BI matrix:

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Works, thanks.  I also decided on adding keys from my item table into the fact table as part of the ETL, which also works.